# How to config transform for a web application in visual studio 2005

Tags: asp.net, config

How can we create a config transform for a web application in visual studio 2005?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

web.config transforms were a new feature in Visual Studio 2010. They did not exist in VS2005.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any Add in available for VS 2005 to do this?

Comment: Not as far as I know. There is "[SlowCheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)", but that's only available for VS2010 and VS2012. Were you aware that you can use these later versions, but still target .NET 2.0?